# How to pass searchview text from action bar to new activity? in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar, searchview

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       searchView = (SearchView)menu
            .findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();   
       SearchManager searchManager = 
            (SearchManager)getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
       searchView.setSearchableInfo(
             searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
       return true;
}
```

**Should I code new method in which i get query from searchview and then pass 
   it on using Intent?** Like

```
public void getInput()
    {
      String input = (String)searchView.getQuery();

      Intent in = new Intent(this, search_result.class);
      //TITLE is an instance variable
      //public static final String TITLE = "title";
        in.putExtra(TITLE, input);
        startActivity(in);
     }
```

**(OR)**

Should I write in OnCreate method of MainActivity?

(By the way I am having searchview in content_main.xml of navigation drawer 
activity, I need to get input from here and pass it on to another activity's 
textview)

Comment: Thank you @savepopulation for editing:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this way
>   **set search text Listener like below**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
       searchView = (SearchView)menu
            .findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();   
       SearchManager searchManager = 
            (SearchManager)getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
       searchView.setSearchableInfo(
             searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
               getInput(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                return false;
            }
        });
       return true;
}
```

**pass searchText in Intent**

```
public void getInput(String searchText)
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(this, search_result.class);
        in.putExtra("TITLE", searchText);
        startActivity(in);
     }
```

**UPDATE**

use below code to get seachtext in `onCreate()` of `search_result.java` and pass it to method where you want to perform any action according to sarchText

```
String searchText = getIntent().getStringExtra("TITLE");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer:) and this is still not working for me...let me explain there is a searchview in action bar when user clicks, it opens and  take the input. After entering when user clicks search icon in android keyboard or press enter it should get the text entered and pass it on to new activity where specific function gets it via intent

Comment: Hello sir, I have coded the same way as you mentioned and i am getting the text perfectly. I have one more query- following the above mentioned question I have a method in search_result.java, so I need this input to be used in that method to perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code

```
Intent in = new Intent(this , Search_result.class);
in.putExtra("tag",input);
startActivity(in);
```

Get input from Serch_result Activity by using,

```
getIntent().getExtras().getString("tag");
```

Comment: thank you for the answer:) and this is still not working for me...let me explain there is a searchview in action bar when user clicks, it opens and  take the input. After entering when user clicks search icon in android keyboard or press enter it should get the text entered and pass it on to new activity where specific function gets it via intent